# Missing values property not working in KNIME

Tags: knime

I am trying to catch missing values as "missing" or "N/A" but nothing seems to working.

In image I have tried "missing", "N/A", "Not Available" words but it skips the missing values when no element found on DOM. Is there any way to capture those values.

e.g. I am trying to find out the facebook post reactions but if a post have no reaction, i want "missing" string instead KNIME skip that element.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how DOM missing values are related to an Excel sheet appender missing value handling. Could you please clarify where is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is always difficult to say something about Knime node behavior in specific workflows since the previous nodes can influence the expected result in several different ways. If you can provide a link to access to an example workflow that replicates your problem it could be easier for the community to understand your issue and try to help you.

Now, I can suggest you to look at 3 easy alternatives:

1. Use `missing value node` in order to input that "Not available".
2. verify whether this behavior only happens with `excel sheet appender
   node`. Maybe read the file, append those values with `concatenate
   node` and write down the updated data can help.
3. What about use google connector nodes to write into spreadsheet instead excel?